# Integrals that have yet to be solved - are there any?

Tags: calculus, integration, closed-form, elementary-functions

I wounder whether there are any Integrals that are known to have a solution in terms of elementary functions only (or that it is unknown whether they have an elementary solution), but couldn't be solved until now?

I have read about [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) already which can in principle answer this question, but there are cases where the algorithm fails because of the [constant problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_problem).

So, the question is, in these cases where the algorithm fails, is there (always) some way to get the result at least manually/approximatly? Or are there any integrals which haven't been solved where its unknown whether they have an elementary antiderivative?

Comment: I'm no expert, but based on the linked pages: If $\alpha$ is some real expression for which "$\alpha = 0$" is unknown (and Difficult to Decide), the question of whether or not $f(x) = e^{\alpha x^{2}}$ has an elementary antiderivative is Equally Difficult.

Comment: Hm ok, that sounds reasonable... do you know some $\alpha(x)$ for which this is really hard to decide (or better: unknown)?

Comment: @SampleTime A cheeky answer: Define $\alpha$ to be the number of nontrivial zeroes of the Riemann Zeta function that lie off the critical line (or $\pi$ if there are infinitely many). If the Riemann Hypothesis is true, then $\alpha=0$, otherwise, $\alpha>0$.

Comment: @MarkS. It is know that if RH is false, then there are infinitely many (in fact a positive fraction) zeros off the critical line. So $\alpha=0$ or $\alpha=\pi$.